# How to call the WebApi,Implemented with AttributeRouting for each action methods,calling it from my client and passing the Query parameters in url?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have implemented attribute routing for each of action methods in My Webapi.
Example of action method is:-

```
[Route("api/DocumentApi/DeleteDocument/{fileInfoId}/{customerAccountName}")]
      [HttpDelete]
      public HttpResponseMessage DeleteDocument(int fileInfoId, string customerAccountName)
      {

            //***
            //*** Some body contents
            //***
      }
```

Now i want to call the above action method from the client example( Fiddler Web debugger),or browser and want to pass the Url request in the below pattern:-

```
http://{localhost:9791}/api/DocumentApi/DeleteDocument?fileInfoId=12&customerAccountName="Manish"
```

Currently i am not able to hit the above action method by the above specified url request. 
But if i use the url pattern like below:-

`http://{localhost:9791}/api/DocumentApi/DeleteDocument/12/Manish`

I am able to hit the above action method.But for my project requirement,I need to use the Url with query parameters only.
Please suggest me the approach,how to achieve this?
Any response will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Route templates in Web API do not support specifying query string parameters. For your scenario, do not define `fileInfoId` and `customerAccountName` as part of your route template as doing so makes Web API to strictly look for 5 segments(the text between the `/` characters in your route template) in your request url...so just modify your route template to `[Route("api/DocumentApi/DeleteDocument")]` and keep the parameters on the actions as it is...

Comment: I appreciate the answer,but my question is that,if i have two action methods with the same name for Example:- If i have two methods in the same controller with same Route template [Route("api/DocumentApi/DeleteDocument")] and [Route("api/DocumentApi/DeleteDocument")],and if both Web Api action methods are taking different input parameters.Then how Web Api will identify both action methods as different methods when it is called from the client e.g. Browser or Fiddler web debugger. Thanks.

Comment: Web API does have action overloading logic which takes care of this kind of scenario...are you seeing anything different here?

Comment: Now My Issue is almost resolved.First thanks for the co-operation.and will be in touch if i face any issue related to it.I really learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use like following code :

```
[Route("api/DocumentApi/DeleteDocument/{fileInfoId}/{customerAccountName}")]      
public HttpResponseMessage TestAction(string fileInfoId,string customerAccountName)
{
```